# iPhone iOS6 audio crashing

Tags: ios, crash, core-audio

We have start to noticing some weird audio bugs for some users after they updated to iOS6. 
We are using the `MPMusicPlayerController` and some other core audio features. Anyone else experienced something similar? Console log snippet:

```
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< ERROR:    23:14:43.712 [tid 0x2ff6f000] VirtualStream.cpp[465]: GetCurrentFormats(): Error 'what' getting virtual format for actual format [ 16/44100/1; flags: 0x44; bytes/packet: 4; frames/packet: 1; bytes/frame: 4;  ]
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< EXCEPTION: 23:14:43.718 [tid 0x2ff6f000] VirtualStream.cpp[369]: GetPropertyData(): result: "error getting current stream format"
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< ERROR:    23:14:43.731 [tid 0x2ff6f000] VirtualStream.cpp[465]: GetCurrentFormats(): Error 'what' getting virtual format for actual format [ 16/44100/1; flags: 0x44; bytes/packet: 4; frames/packet: 1; bytes/frame: 4;  ]
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< ERROR:    23:14:43.738 [tid 0x2ff6f000] VirtualAudio_Stream.cpp[411]: UpdatePhysicalFormat(): error 'what' getting underlying stream format
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone Application[3009] <Warning>: [DB] phone volume changed to: 1.000000
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< ERROR:    23:14:43.858 [tid 0x3265000] VirtualStream.cpp[465]: GetCurrentFormats(): Error 'what' getting virtual format for actual format [ 16/44100/1; flags: 0x44; bytes/packet: 4; frames/packet: 1; bytes/frame: 4;  ]
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< EXCEPTION: 23:14:43.863 [tid 0x3265000] AggregateDevice_Common.cpp[1204]: UpdateIOProcCache(): result: "Stream::GetCurrentFormat() returned an error."
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: >vad< EXCEPTION: 23:14:43.867 [tid 0x3265000] VirtualAudio_Device.cpp[2186]: StartIOEngine(): theError: "error starting IO on the active device"
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Error>: 23:14:43.870 <AudioControl> AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO: error 2003329396
Sep 30 23:14:43 JMS-iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Error>: 23:14:43.872 <AudioControl> AQMEDevice(0x1ea4e000)::StartIO: error 2003329396
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but only on iPhone 4 (not 4S or 5).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think we have solved this for now. What really happend was that we had not fully understand the complexity in both background audio and audio session interruptions.

If you have weird sound problems check that you are handling the interruptions correctly.

Sorry for not providing any code, for more informations on handling interruptions:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html